# Buy analog photographic material in Kiev and Odessa

Tags: photography, ukraine, kyiv

I am looking for a shop in Kiev and Odessa where I can buy analog photographic film and paper. Does anyone know a shop were I can buy this?

(May be this is not the right place to ask such kind of question but since many experienced travelers and maybe also ukranian locals use this forum I wanted to post this question here.)

Comment: I think this is on-topic for travel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can buy them at the [ФОТОФОНД (PHOTOFOND) store](https://vk.com/club3237218) in Central Kiev, which has two locations:

1. > ФОТОЛАВКА: ул. Шота Руставели, 8 (вход со двора)

**Translation:** [Fotolavka, Shota Rustaveli st., 8 (entrance from the courtyard)](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB.+%D0%A8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0+%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%96,+8,+%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2,+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/@50.436232,30.528645,14z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x40d4ceffab64ee8d:0xdfbd51cc1f5f3e3a?hl=ru)

Phone: (044) 235-33-35, 234-85-22

2. > ФОТОМАСТЕР: ул. Горького (Антоновича), 4/6

**Translation:** [Fotomaster, Gorkiy (Antonovich) st., 4/6](https://www.google.com/maps/place/%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BB.+%D0%90%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0,+4%2F6,+%D0%9A%D0%B8%D1%97%D0%B2,+%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0/@50.44472,30.513712,14z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x40d4cefbe389949f:0xb0e85bfedb3fbe78?hl=ru)

Phone: (044) 287-50-98, 289-41-38